# Recommend method to update codes and install newer version of the script

Tags: magento, updates

The developer of the script often updates the scripts and releases newer versions.

For instance, If am currently using the version 2.0, i'd create changes within the script to suit my requirements. However, if there is a new version released with new features, I would want to have the newer features while maintaining the changes I did manually.

If i simply update and replace, my changes would be gone. So I need a few tips that would enable to me to update to the newer version of the script effectively.

Its a heavy script based on Magento with many files.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to answer with such a simple solution, but have you looked into using Git (github.com) to help manage code updates and revisions? I use it successfully in a windows / linux development environment for a magento / wcf-workflow / asp.net / windows service combined solution for over 3 years now.  I have history back until the first bit of code that was written.

We all have our own origin repository forked from the upstream, and it also allows one person to be in charge of code merges via the merge request option.

It also has the ability to be configured to automatically push to a server if you push to a specific branch.

You might look into it. It has been an extreme benefit to our small team of 5 people.